# Rewrite a directory to / while keeping actual directory structure in tact?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, 301-redirect

My site exists www.site.com/forum I have no need for /forum but I do not want to go through the effort of changing everything.  Is there a way I can get Apache to rewrite the URL so that it uses the root instead of /forum?

It's a Django app otherwise I would just 301 and change the document root.

Thanks

Comment: Are the URLs hardcoded in the application's returned HTML/CSS/JS to the absolute (ie `src="/forum/images/resource.jpg"`) path, or are they relative (ie `src="images/resource.jpg"`)?

Comment: How are you hosting this?  `mod_wsgi`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the resources are all well-behaved about relative pathing, you should be able to just rewrite the paths.

Try this in the `<VirtualHost>` section:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond !^/forum [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) /forum/$1 [L,PT]
```

The `RewriteCond` is designed to leave alone anything that's requesting a path starting with `/forum`, instead of sending the request to `/forum/forum`.  It may catch errant hardcoded paths, and keep old links alive.